# @for and @each to generate grid column classes in Sass

Tags: for-loop, sass, grid, media-queries, each

I'm trying find the way to create dynamic column classes in Sass for the website I'm working on. And this is what I have so far:

```
$breakpoints: (small: 0, medium: 640px, large: 1024px);
$grid-columns: 12;

@for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
  @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
    .#{$key}-#{$i} { width: (100% / $grid-columns) * $i }
  }
}
```

This is what I get after compilation:

```
.small-1 { width: 8.33333%; }

.medium-1 { width: 8.33333%; }

.large-1 { width: 8.33333%; }

.small-2 { width: 16.66667%; }

.medium-2 { width: 16.66667%; }

.large-2 { width: 16.66667%; }

...
```

But in fact, this is what I would like to get:

```
.small-1, .medium-1, .large-1 { width: 8.33333%; }

.small-2, .medium-2, .large-2 { width: 16.66667%; }

...
```

Any ideas out there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I made a mistake and didn't think much ahead, because in fact, what I was actually going to need was the following output:

```
.small-1 { width: 8.33333%; }
.small-2 { width: 16.66667%; }
.small-3 { width: 25%; }
...

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  /* line 43, ../scss/_grid.scss */
  .medium-1 { width: 8.33333%; }
  .medium-2 { width: 16.66667%; }
  .medium-3 { width: 25%; }
  ...
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .large-1 { width: 8.33333%; }
  .large-2 { width: 16.66667%; }
  .large-3 { width: 25%; }
  ...
}
```

And I achieved that throught the following code:

```
$breakpoints: (small: 0, medium: 640px, large: 1024px);
$grid-columns: 12;

@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
  @if $value == 0 {
    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
      .#{$key}-#{$i} { width: (100% / $grid-columns) * $i; };
    }
  } @else if $value != 0 {
    @include breakpoint(#{$key}) {;
    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
      .#{$key}-#{$i} { width: (100% / $grid-columns) * $i; };
    };
    };
  }
}
```

Hope this can also be helpful to someone else ;)

Edit: Since @Ram Kumar got a little curious about the `@include breakpoint(#{$key})` part, I'm adding the mixin code behind that right below. There must be a better or simpler way of doing it, but this what I could come up with. If you're looking for a simple solution, you will only need the first lines of the following:

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {

    // breakpoint(medium), breakpoint(large)...
    @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
        @if $point == $key and not ($value == 0) {
            @media only screen and (min-width: #{$value}) { @content; }
        }
    }

    // breakpoint(small only), breakpoint(medium only), breakpoint(large only)...
    $i: 1;
    @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {

        $bp-only: $key only;
        $bp-keys: map-keys($breakpoints);
        $bp-values: map-values($breakpoints);

        @if $point == $bp-only and $value == 0 {
            @media only screen and (max-width: #{nth($bp-values, $i + 1)}) { @content; }
        }
        @if $point == $bp-only and not ($value == 0) and not ($key == nth($bp-keys, -1)) {
            @media only screen and (min-width: #{$value}) and (max-width: #{nth($bp-values, $i)}) { @content; }
        }
        @if $point == $bp-only and $key == nth($bp-keys, -1) {
            @media only screen and (min-width: #{$value}) { @content; }
        }

        $i: $i + 1;
    }

    // breakpoint(medium down), breakpoint(large down)...
    @each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
        $bp-down: $key down;
        @if $point == $bp-down and not ($value == 0) {
            @media only screen and (max-width: #{$value}) { @content; }
        }
    }

}
```